# Delete uploaded files when calling transaction.set_rollback() on the View

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a simple file upload function as shown below:

Model:

```
class ImageUpload(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Serializer:

```
class ImageUploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ImageUpload
    fields = ['id', 'image']
```

View:

```
class TestView(APIView):

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request):
        # some logic code
        serializer = ImageUploadSerializer(data={
            'image': request.FILES['file']
        })
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        if something_bad_happen:
            transaction.set_rollback(True)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Ok, if everything is normal, I will have an image file saved to the hard disk on the server and a record stored in the database. When I called `transaction.set_rollback(True)` in View, Django did the rollback perfectly and no records were added to the database. But after I recheck, Django didn't delete the image file on my hard disk even though there is no record in the DB associated with that image file.

I also searched and got a solution like `post_delete`:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=ImageUpload)
def auto_delete_file_on_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.image:
        if os.path.isfile(instance.image.path):
            os.remove(instance.image.path)
```

This seems to work only when I call `delete()` method but with not with transactions.

How can I delete unnecessary files during upload file when my View raising exception or `transaction.set_rollback(True)` function is called?

Comment: `serializer.save()` returns an instance of the object (not sure if it does in `transaction.atomic`), did you try to remove image from your file system directly after rollback, accessing the filename from the instance? i.e. `instance = serializer.save()` and if something bad happens: `os.remove(instance.image.path)`

Comment: @Ersain This only partially solves my problem, it will only work when I know for sure where my code exceptions is. Doesn't work out if Django raise exception that I couldn't know before

Comment: @Ersain Of course the problem will be solved your way too if I put the try catch on the entire block of code. But I don't think this is a good way to do it.

Comment: @DoTrungDuc Transactions work at the database level and can only roll back the database operations performed. Your file is not be stored in DB so on rollback DB can not delete that. As @Ersain mentioned you need to handle exceptions and do the file cleanup explicitly. You can use the `Exception` class to catch all sort of exceptions.